# Sql - Order by integer/string

Tags: php, sql, int, varchar

I am using this select in my query:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT column FROM table WHERE category = :category ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT 4");
```

However, this is how the column works:

```
clicks varchar(10) NOT NULL,
```

So its not exactly an integer, but a string...

Is this the reason why the query does not work properly?
Is there any way to fix it?

Greetings!

Comment: We have no idea what's wrong with it - you didn't tell us.

Comment: @YCS, This one is PDO related, please don't rollback.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the query not working properly? What output are you getting? And what output are you expecting?

Comment: if i have (12,3,22,50) in my database, it is displayed in this order: 12,3,22,50

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is of course to make the column an integer, but if you really cannot change it, you can use something like this (kind of a hack though...):

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE category = :category 
  ORDER BY LENGTH(clicks) DESC, clicks DESC LIMIT 4
```